# How to extract values separated by white space in Python arrays

Tags: python, arrays, multidimensional-array

I have a variable of type <class 'numpy.ndarray'>.It is 2dim Array Python

Q = [[0.5 0.5 ] [0.99876063 0.99876063]]

My question is how to extract 0.998 and 0.998 from the last row and save them into 2 different variables ?

Comment: `var1, var2 = Q[1]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can try this

```
x, y = Q[-1][0],Q[-1][1]
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

`a, b = Q[1][0], Q[1][1]`

Answer (score 0):

```py
import numpy as np

Q = np.array([[0.5,0.5 ],[0.99876063,0.99876063]])

v1,v2 = Q[1][0],Q[1][1]

print(v1,v2)
```

This should work